# OpenCV, Python, cv2 error: (-5:Bad argument) Empty training data was given.You'll need more than one sample to learn a model. in function 'train'

Tags: python, opencv

This is my code. I have a learning problem. Gives the error

> error: (-5:Bad argument) Empty training data was given. You'll need more than one sample to learn a model. in function 'train'.

I can't solve this problem. I can't find an explanation on how to fix it? Where can I read about the solution to this problem? My pictures have size 200x200, format .pgm.

```
import os

import cv2
import numpy as np


def read_images(path, image_size):
    names = []
    training_images, training_labels = [], []
    label = 0
    for dirname, subdirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for subdirname in subdirnames:
            names.append(subdirname)
            subject_path = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
            for filename in os.listdir(subject_path):
                img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(subject_path, filename),
                                 cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                if img is None:
                    # The file cannot be loaded as an image.
                    # Skip it.
                    continue
                img = cv2.resize(img, image_size)
                training_images.append(img)
                training_labels.append(label)
            label += 1
    training_images = np.asarray(training_images, np.uint8)
    training_labels = np.asarray(training_labels, np.int32)
    return names, training_images, training_labels


path_to_training_images = '/home/ace/OpenCV/cascades/A_M'# not properly. This is  = '/home/ace/OpenCV/cascades/'

training_image_size = (200, 200)
names, training_images, training_labels = read_images(path_to_training_images, training_image_size)

model = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()
model.train(training_images, training_labels)

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
while (cv2.waitKey(1) == -1):
    success, frame = camera.read()
    if success:
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.3, 5)
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            roi_gray = gray[x:x+w, y:y+h]
            if roi_gray.size == 0:
                # The ROI is empty. Maybe the face is at the image edge.
                # Skip it.
                continue
            roi_gray = cv2.resize(roi_gray, training_image_size)
            label, confidence = model.predict(roi_gray)
            text = '%s, confidence=%.2f' % (names[label], confidence)
            cv2.putText(frame, text, (x, y - 20),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('Face Recognition', frame)
```

Comment: Please print the `shape` of the numpy arrays `training_images` and `training_labels` directly after calling `read_images` and share the result with us!

Comment: ` ace@ace:~/OpenCV/cascades$ python3 face_recog1.py
[]
[]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_recog1.py", line 41, in <module>
    model.train(training_images, training_labels)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /io/opencv_contrib/modules/face/src/eigen_faces.cpp:62: error: (-5:Bad argument) Empty training data was given. You'll need more than one sample to learn a model. in function 'train'`

Comment: here is the result, empty arrays

Comment: Now go on debugging your code. Check: How often is your `os.walk` loop repeated? Which files are found? Do you pass the right path?

Comment: ace@ace:~/OpenCV/cascades$ python3 face_recog.py
                                                                                                                                   **/home/ace/OpenCV/cascades/A_M**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_recog.py", line 43, in <module>
    names, training_images, training_labels = read_img(path_to_training_images,                           **I printed the path variable, I got the correct path to my images, but the array is empty.**

Comment: Ok, please share your subfolder structure with us. Are the images always at the same depth like `<path>/<dirname>/<subdirname>/<filename>` or do you have different cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it seems a little bit odd that you use recursive `walk`-function and then seperately list the subdirectories, your `read_images` function works for me if I create a folder structure like this:

```
images/
  - sub1/
    - img1.png
    - img2.png
  - sub2/
    - img3.png
    - img4.png
```

The files are found and the return values are filled. Probably your folder structure differs from what your code expects.

You can try to debug your setup with some further print-statements like this:

```
def read_images(path, image_size):
    names = []
    training_images, training_labels = [], []
    label = 0
    for dirname, subdirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        print(f"dirname={dirname}")
        for subdirname in subdirnames:
            print(f"- subdirname={subdirname}")
            names.append(subdirname)
            subject_path = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
            for filename in os.listdir(subject_path):
                print(f"  - filename={filename}")
                img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(subject_path, filename),
                                 cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                if img is None:
                    # The file cannot be loaded as an image.
                    # Skip it.
                    continue
                img = cv2.resize(img, image_size)
                training_images.append(img)
                training_labels.append(label)
            label += 1
    training_images = np.asarray(training_images, np.uint8)
    training_labels = np.asarray(training_labels, np.int32)
    return names, training_images, training_labels
```

Please check the output of those prints and compare it with your folder structure. If this doesn't help, please share the debug output and your folder structure with us. Please don't share it as comment but by updating your question!

Comment: There was a wrong folder structure, I specified access not to a directory with data on all images, but to a specific folder with only one type of images. Your answer helped me figure it out. Thank you very mach.